# vector subscript out of range - bubble sort

Tags: c++, vector, sorting

I've got this piece of code that implements a bubble sorting of an array.
Being compiled in MS VS 2012 it works up to a point:

UPD: I've added a lot of checking to trace the exact place where a crash happens, an it's like this:
it swaps the first two elements of an array, prints out an array with those elements swapped, then it prints out "Checking" and crashes with "vector subscript out of range"

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;


int Check(vector<int> Array)
{
printf ("Checking: \n");
for (int i = 0; i < Array.size(); i++)
    if((int*) Array[i] == NULL)
    {
        cerr << "Array [" << i << "] is fubared";
        return -1;
    }
}

int PrintOut(vector<int> Array)
{
printf ("Your array appears to be as follows: \n");
for (int i = 0; i < Array.size(); i++)
    printf("%d  ", Array[i]);
return 0;
}

int bubble_sort()
{
int or_size = 2;
int i, j, size, temp;

printf("Specify array size\n");
scanf_s("%d", &size);
printf(" Now, input all elements of the array \n");

vector<int> Array(size, 0);
if (size > or_size)
    Array.resize(size);

for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    printf("Array [%d] is now re-initialised as ", i);
    scanf_s("%d", &temp);
    printf("\n");
    Array[i] = temp;
}

Check(Array);

PrintOut(Array);

for (i = 1; i < size; i++)
    for (j = 0; j < size-i ; j--)
    {
        printf ("Attempting to swap Array[%d], which = %d, and Array [%d], which = %d \n",j, Array[j], j+1, Array[j+1]);
        if (Array[j] > Array[j+1])
        {
            Array[j]+=Array[j+1];
            Array[j+1] = Array[j] - Array[j+1];
            Array[j] = Array[j] - Array[j+1];
            printf("Swapped \n");
        }
        PrintOut(Array);
        Check(Array);
    }

printf ("\n Your Array has been bubble_sorted and should know look like this: \n");
for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
    printf("%d ", Array[i]);

Array.clear();

return 0;
}

int main()
{
    bubble_sort();
    return 0;
}
```

It must be something really simple, but just out of my reach. 
PS
No embarrassing _asm now ;-)

Comment: why are you even bothering with the asm?  The compiler can make that code as good as you can.

Comment: I think you've got a loop variable problem in your `for (j = size; ...)` loop... Actually a couple of them - one involving `i` instead of `j`, and the other starting with `size`, which is past the end of your array.

Comment: @AlanBaljeu Since the only good reason for coding a bubble-sort is as a coding exercise, presumably they're using asm to learn asm.

Comment: I agree. I do not believe there is a good reason to use asm for the swap. Other than this being a homework assignment where asm was required.

Comment: please, just ignore _asm. I'm sure it doesn't come into this. Yes, I am learning it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got an "off-by-one" error:

```
for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
    for (j = size; i > 0; i--)
    //   ^^^^
    //   j is out or range, the last valid index is size-1
        if (Array[j] < Array[j-1])
            swap(Array[j], Array[j-1]);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
for (j = size; i > 0; i--)
```

must became

```
for (j = size - 1; i > 0; i--)
```

for an array of dimension N index goes from 0 to N - 1

Comment: I feel like some `i`s and `j`s are mixed up in this code as well